# How to Convert String^ Array to Void* Array

Tags: arrays, type-conversion, c++-cli

Development environment: Win32 Desktop Application C++/CLI

Let's have an array like this:

```
array<String^>^ strArr = gcnew array<String^>(100);
```

An array like this too:

```
void* ptrArr[100];
```

I have to copy all the first array's elements to second array. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that `void* ptrArr[100]` is actually `const char* ptrArr[100]`. `void*` could be literally anything, so there's no way to answer the question without making an assumption about the type.

So, you need two things here: You need to do the conversion between types (including from Unicode code points to ANSI characters), and you need to have something own that memory.

There's a few choices as to what should hold the unmanaged memory for the `const char*`. The most do-it-yourself route is [`Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobalansi), but that's a pain so we're going to skip that. (This would require manually keeping track of a bunch of `IntPtr`, and manually calling `FreeHGlobal` when done.)

The other choices are different invocations of [`marshal_as`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/marshal-as).

You could convert all the `String^` instances into `std::string` instances, and pull the `const char*` out of them. I recommend `marshal_as<std::string>` for this. In this case, the memory is owned by the `std:string` instances, so `ptrArr` will be valid only for as long as `stdStrArr` is.

```
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

array<String^>^ strArr = gcnew array<String^>(100);
std::string stdStrArr[100];
const char* ptrArr[100];

for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    stdStrArr[i] = marshal_as<std::string>(strArr[i]);
    ptrArr[i] = stdStrArr[i].c_str();
}
// Memory for ptrArr deallocated when stdStrArr goes out of scope.
```

The other choice is to use `marshal_as` to convert directly to `const char*`. To do this, you allocate a helper object. In this case, the memory is owned by the [`marshal_context`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/marshal-context-class) instance, so  `ptrArr` will be valid only for as long as `context` is.

```
#include <msclr\marshal.h>

array<String^>^ strArr = gcnew array<String^>(100);
marshal_context^ context = gcnew marshal_context();
char* ptrArr[100];

for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    ptrArr[i] = context->marshal_as<const char*>(strArr[i]);
}
// Memory for ptrArr deallocated when you call `delete context`, or when it's garbage collected.
```

Further reading:

- [Overview of Marshaling in C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/overview-of-marshaling-in-cpp)
- [`marshal_context::marshal_as`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/marshal-context-marshal-as) (Shows an example of using a `marshal_context`.)

<sub>Notes:</sub>

- <sub>I didn't check my syntax with a compiler. There may be small errors.</sub>
- <sub>It seems like there should be a question to mark this one a duplicate. However, I wasn't able to find a "convert String^ to char*" question that was highly-rated, used `marshal_as` in the answer, and showed a good example of how to use it.</sub>

Comment: Of course, Unicode to any "ANSI" character set could be very lossy.